# Using alternative identity file for SSH connection but ssh offers default key instead

Tags: ssh

My server has a `~/.ssh/authorized keys` file with 2 entries. The first one without options, the second one with options.

The first entry is the default key on the client (`~/.ssh/id_rsa`). The second entry is the test key on the client (`~/ssh-keys/ssh-test-key`).

When I connect using the command `ssh -v -i ~/ssh-keys/ssh-test-key [server]` I expect ssh to use the second entry to authenticate. However, it does not. Looking at the debug output from ssh, it says `debug1: Offering public key: [...] /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa`. That's not the key I want it to use.

It connects just fine, it just authenticates with the wrong key. (The reason this matters is because I'm trying to setup a key that only allows a single command, for use by a CI system. And I don't want to give it any more access than it needs.)

Content of `authorized_keys`:

```
command="./do-stuff.sh",no-port-forwarding,no-x11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding ssh-rsa [publickey] single-command
ssh-rsa [publickey] something@something
```

Output of ssh command:

```
$ ssh -v -i ./ssh-key-test [server]
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to [server] [*.*.*.*] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file ./ssh-key-test type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file ./ssh-key-test-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to [server]:22 as 'coo'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:vQ/06aAndjHeQvAFTx5d3m/xgP5K3mZxp81yQiFo/68
debug1: Host '[server]' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:80
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:Pzl+YrYbXeHaBGn2dExkw34Xy9KsvkBtWj8XlK15fpA /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to [server] ([*.*.*.*]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = en_GB.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = en_GB.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = en_GB.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_SG.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = en_GB.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = en_GB.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = en_GB.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = en_GB.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = en_GB.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = en_GB.UTF-8
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-91-generic x86_64)
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

After restarting `ssh-agent` on the client, it works as intended. I don't understand why the ssh-agent is related to this, so if anyone does, please let me know.

To kill (and restart) ssh-agent:

```sh
# will give you the pid
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
# kill it
kill -9 [pid]
# Check to see it now has a different pid (i.e. it got killed and restarted)
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```